# Twitter Bootstrap content overflowing in ie6 and ie7

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I know enough CSS to be dangerous and have hit a bit of a wall with IE6 and IE7 using Twitter Bootstrap's fluid grid. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I've tried some of the suggestions here and elsewhere, but keep coming up empty.

Because I wanted to add space between my two columns of text I created two .inner classes with padding. This worked like magic in everything except IE6 and IE7, where the .span4 content overflows the container.

[image: content overflows its container in IE7]

Can someone help me understand the source of this padding problem and what I need to do? Many thanks!

```
#main {padding: 0 5% 3% 5%;}
.inner-left {padding-right: 5%;}
.inner-right {padding-left: 2%;}


<div id="content" class="fluid-row">
<div id="main" class="span12" role="main">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8">
       <div class="inner-left">
          <p>text</p>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span4">
       <div class="inner-right">
         <p>text</p>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: could you elaborate further with help of some screenshot about what you are trying to achieve as at present things look fine to me..

Comment: @RishiKalia because this was my first post on Stackoverflow, it wouldn't let me upload a screenshot. But with your comment, my reputation jumped high enough to allow me to upload. Thank you!

Comment: You can try [bsie](http://ddouble.github.com/bsie/), the Bootstrap IE6 compatible library: [http://ddouble.github.com/bsie/](http://ddouble.github.com/bsie/)

Answer (score 1):

you may replace your code with this:

```
<div class="inner-right" style="margin-right:70px">
<blockquote><p>What do you plan to do with your one wild and precious life?</p>
<p><small>Mary Oliver</small></p></blockquote>
</div>
```

or you may edit your app.css as below:

```
.inner-right {
padding-left: 2%;
margin-right:70px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for directing my attention to the right margins! This was a huge help. I ended up targeting IE7 using the * trick. Will  modify the answer with what what I ended up doing. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: @sticklechick I'd also recommend making it the accepted answer.